# Problems with Compiling a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, anaconda

I am trying to compile a simple Hello World C++ program on my new Conda environment, but it returns a exit status as shown below.

```
/home/ep/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

g++ is also installed, and libstdc++.so is also found in lib director of anaconda3.

```
g++ (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.131_87df0e6_dirty) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Could anyone suggest to me how to solve this issue?

Comment: My question may sound odd, but what filesystem do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need also install the development files of library `libstdc++`

E.g In you are in Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-8-dev
```